# How can I change the CSS for Phpmyadmin so tooltips aren't covered by my cursor?

Tags: css, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin in XAMPP.

For an example, when I hover my cursor over a database in the side panel, a tooltip appears. It says 'structure'. I can only see 'cture'.

Is there a way to change the CSS inside the phpmyadmin/themes folder to make the font bigger or change the tooltip position? I've tried changing anything with .tooltip as a selector, but I haven't had any success...

Comment: That is default browser styling fot title tag. You might modified the browser defaults.